# Entity Framework generated classes are not in the namespace I require, is there a way of changing the namespace it uses without regenerating?

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, namespaces

If I need to regenerate where should the namespace be specified. I am trying to use partial classes from within the Models namespace however they don't match.

The simplified code fragment below is where the entity framework classes have been generated

```
namespace projectname
{
   #region Contexts

   /// <summary>
  /// No Metadata Documentation available.
  /// </summary>
  public partial class MyClass
  {

  }
}
```

When I add a class to my models folder,

```
namespace projectname.Models
{

    public partial class MyClass
    {
     //etc, etc 
    }
}
```

As you can see the namespaces don't match causing issues when I try and use them as the compiler is seeing both projectname.Models.MyClass and projectname.MyClass.

I would like some advice on the correct way to fix this, preferably to update the E.F. classes so they exist in the projectname.Models namespace, but I am not sure how to go about it.

Comment: Can you please show us some of your code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IIRC, if you are using an Entity data model, you should be able to change the namespace directly through the xml file or files (you may have to change it for all the various storage and and conceptual models).  There might even be some way to change it in the designer.. seems simple enough.

Actually, the solution might be here:

[Generated Code Overview (Entity Data Model Designer)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc982041%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (see Custom Tool Namespace)

Comment: Your answer is correct, however when I run Custom Tool it does nothing, so eventually I had to change the files manually to match the namespace. Unfortunately I can't vote you up as I don't have 15 reputation points.

Comment: Note, you should change Custom Tool Names of .tt file, not .edmx

Comment: Good catch. I was updating the .edmx and not the Model.tt

Comment: @JohnFleming You can however accept the answer as correct!

Answer (score 13):

In line with Roman O's comment, namespace can be changed by updating "Custom Tool Namespace" property of text transform (.tt) file, which ties generated entity classes (in Database First approach) to entity model (.edmx) file. This works in VS 2012 Express with EF 5.0.

I would post a screenshot but for lack of reputation.

Comment: Upvoted, because this answer specifically mentions the ´.tt´ files. You can change the Custom Tool Namespace for the ´.edmx´, but that will do nothing for generated files. You have to change Custom Tool Namespace for the T4 scripts (context and/or entities).

Answer (score 3):

- Right click the .edmx file in the project in Solution Explorer and select Properties
- In the VS properties pane, fine Custom Tool Namespace
- Enter the full CLR namespace you'd like
- Rebuild the project

Answer (score 1):

Namespace of auto-generated classes will be inherited from VS project settings (and even change if you change it there). Of course you should have "Custom Tool Namespace" property empty. (just tested it with VS2013 and EF6.1)
Unlike settings files which had always been pita :)

For older version there is a good video on manual changing :

https://youtu.be/B7Cqc9F0Ih8